# How can i input value into object of javascipt?

Tags: javascript

```
let inputInf=document.getElementById('inputInf');

let nameStudent=inputInf;

let output= new Student(nameStudent,number);
 
document.getElementById("btn").onclick=(event)=>{
     let xuatTTMH=document.getElementById("outputInfor");
     xuatTTMH.innerHTML=output.nameStudent;    
}
```

I thought I can do it this way but the answer is `[object HTMLInputElement]`. Can you please help me to solve this problem or give me the keyword of this situation?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Would you post your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the value of `nameStudent` is `[object HTMLInputElement]`? It's because you didn't get the value from the input field. For the first line, it should be:

```
let inputInf = document.getElementById('inputInf').value;
```

Comment: i have tried but it's still not working :(

Comment: define "still not working". Still the same result you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a HTMLInputElement object

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

There is a 'value' property that you need to check to get the object value from your  inputInf var.

Comment: you mean that i should add '.value' after inputInf right? i tried but it's still not working...